# Reading VRT from SoilGrids in R

Tags: raster, r, vrt, soilgrids

I need the global SOC stocks map at 0-30cm from the new SoilGrids 2.0:
https://files.isric.org/soilgrids/latest/data/ocs/

I have no previous experience with VRT files. I have simply downloaded "ocs_0-30cm_mean.vrt" and "ocs_0-30cm_mean.vrt.ovr". Honestly, I don't know if I need one, the other, or both.

In R, I load it with the raster package.

```
soc <- raster("ocs_0-30cm_mean.vrt.ovr") # t/ha
soc
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 14509, 39812, 577632308  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent     : 0, 39812, 0, 14509  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : NA 
source     : ocs_0-30cm_mean.vrt.ovr 
names      : ocs_0.30cm_mean.vrt 
values     : -32768, 32767  (min, max)
```

However, the resolution appears to be 1 degree, when it should be 250m. The extent makes no sense (I guess it should be c(-180, 180, -90, 90), and there is no CRS.

I can plot (soc), though I don't know how to change the resolution to e.g. 0.25.
I have also tried the same with "ocs_0-30cm_mean.vrt" (instead of "ocs_0-30cm_mean.vrt.ovr"), but the file does not `plot`

```
plot(soc)
Error in rgdal::getRasterData(con, offset = offs, region.dim = c(1, nc),  : 
  Failure during raster IO
```

How do I make this raster work, with 0.25 resolution and appropriate extent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is better that you consult the Soilgrids FAQ mainly the section [How can I download Soilgrids](https://www.isric.org/explore/soilgrids/faq-soilgrids#How_can_I_access_SoilGrids) the webdav download describes what are the `vrt` and `ovr` files.

`vrt` is a virtual XML file that points to tiles creating a mosaic that behaves like a single file, therefore if you copy only the vrt to your computer you will not get anything, `ovr` are overviews of the `vrt` file

The strange numbers are the homolosine projection give it a look on the [FAQ Homolosine](https://www.isric.org/explore/soilgrids/faq-soilgrids#How_can_I_use_the_Homolosine_projection)

I am not an R programmer but you can access the files on server as a  [GDAL virtual file system](https://gdal.org/user/virtual_file_systems.html) (as if the file would be on your computer and in this case it is `/vsicurl`

```
link<-"/vsicurl/https://files.isric.org/soilgrids/latest/data/ocs/ocs_0-30cm_mean.vrt"
> raster(link)
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 58034, 159246, 9241682364  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 250, 250  (x, y)
extent     : -19949750, 19861750, -6147500, 8361000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=igh +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : /vsicurl/https://files.isric.org/soilgrids/latest/data/ocs/ocs_0-30cm_mean.vrt 
names      : ocs_0.30cm_mean 
values     : 6, 208  (min, max)
```

Pay attention that each layer is **5 gigas compressed**

---

Using `gdalwarp` it is possible to convert the remote `vrt` file into a local geotiff.

```
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 -multi -wm 200 -co BIGTIFF=YES -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co TILED=TRUE \
"/vsicurl?max_retry=3&retry_delay=1&list_dir=no&url=https://files.isric.org/soilgrids/latest/data/ocs/ocs_0-30cm_mean.vrt"
"soc_0-5cm_mean.tif"
```

Just take create that compression is active: `-co COMPRESS=DEFLATE`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer from Jorge Mendes, I can use `gdalUtils` in R to read the online VRT file, transform it to a more friendly projection and resolution, and store a copy in my local disk as a .tif file:

```
# https://files.isric.org/soilgrids/latest/data/ocs/
library(gdalUtils)
gdalwarp(t_srs="EPSG:4326", multi=TRUE, wm=200, 
co=c("BIGTIFF=YES", "COMPRESS=DEFLATE", "TILED=TRUE"),
tr=c(0.25,0.25), # Desired output resolution
verbose=T,
"/vsicurl?max_retry=3&retry_delay=1&list_dir=no&url=https://files.isric.org/soilgrids/latest/data/soc/soc_0-5cm_mean.vrt", # Input VRT
"soc_0-5cm_SoilGrids2.tif") # Output file
```

Comment: I have tried your code but it throws me `Warning message:
In system(cmd, intern = TRUE) :
  running command '"C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\bin\gdalwarp.exe" -multi  -tr 0.25 0.25 -wm "200" -t_srs "EPSG:4326" -of "GTiff" -co "BIGTIFF=YES" -co "COMPRESS=DEFLATE" -co "TILED=TRUE" "/vsicurl?max_retry=3&retry_delay=1&list_dir=no&url=https://files.isric.org/soilgrids/latest/data/soc/soc_0-5cm_mean.vrt" "soc_0-5cm_SoilGrids2.tif"' had status 1`. Can you please look into the issue?