# Soilgrids - Using VRT format in R

Tags: raster, gdal, r, vrt, soilgrids

Is it necessary to use GDAL when trying to use VRT files in R?

#### Raster Attempt

Following [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/361086/read-vrt-from-soilgrids-2-0-in-r) I tried:

```
link <- "/vsicurl/https://files.isric.org/soilgrids/latest/data/clay/clay_0-5cm_mean.vrt"
a <- raster(link)
```

but from there, I can't use `plot()` or `projectRaster()` as with other rasters, e.g. I tried:

```
rast <- projectRaster(a, crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")
```

**GDAL in R**

When trying to follow the [official method](https://git.wur.nl/isric/soilgrids/soilgrids.notebooks/-/blob/master/markdown/wcs_from_R.md) and use GDAL functions like `gdalwarp()`, R cannot find the GDAL installation - which I installed using Conda.

Comment: Why can't you use `plot`? What happens? Is it simply because the VRT points to a ridiculously huge raster? (over 9 billion cells... from nearly 13,000 individual rasters)

Comment: `plot(a$clay_0.5cm_mean[1])` gives me `Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values` but you're right - 'ncell' is incredibly large due to the 250m resolution

Comment: `a$clay_0.5cm_mean[1]` is just the value of the first cell of that raster, and it seems to be NA so its not going to plot in any meaningful way. There are values in there, for example at the centre: `a$clay_0.5cm_mean[nrow(a)/2, ncol(a)/2]` is 220. If that works for you then it proves GDAL is working and its only the network speed and the raster size that's stopping you do stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, and no. A VRT file is a format specified by the GDAL system. It is an XML file that controls the building of a raster from other components. For example here's a section of a VRT where two DEM rasters are referenced:

```
    <ComplexSource>
      <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="1">E020N40.DEM</SourceFilename>
      <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
      <SourceProperties RasterXSize="4800" RasterYSize="6000" DataType="UInt16" BlockXSize="4800" BlockYSize="1"/>
      <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="4800" ySize="6000"/>
      <DstRect xOff="4800" yOff="0" xSize="4800" ySize="6000"/>
      <NODATA>55537</NODATA>
    </ComplexSource>
    <ComplexSource>
      <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="1">E020S10.DEM</SourceFilename>
      <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
      <SourceProperties RasterXSize="4800" RasterYSize="6000" DataType="UInt16" BlockXSize="4800" BlockYSize="1"/>
      <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="4800" ySize="6000"/>
      <DstRect xOff="4800" yOff="6000" xSize="4800" ySize="6000"/>
      <NODATA>-9999</NODATA>
    </ComplexSource>
```

The VRT file itself hides the complexity of accessing those DEMs by appearing to GDAL as a large raster. For any access to the VRT by GDAL, for example "what's the elevation at x,y?", GDAL will look at the XML in the VRT, and go "ah, that will be in `E020S10.DEM`", and then use its code to look in the right place in that file.

Notice the `relativeToVRT` attribute - that tells GDAL where to find the DEM file for this VRT. If you only want a subset of the data then you could download the individual source file and work with that, but even then you'd probably want to use GDAL since its pretty much the only - and best - game in town for reading raster files.

There's two other complications with your example: first you are using `/vsicurl` to access the VRT over the network. I looked at the VRT and its components are also relative to the VRT, so they'll be coming over the network too. This may be slow. Secondly, the dataset is *massive* and so doing anything in R that requires reading in the whole raster will take next-to-forever.